# SFDX force:mdapi:deploy Profile Search Layout: - System Administrator - not appropriate for object

Tags: salesforcedx, search-layout, mdapi, mdapideploy

I am trying to use force:mdapi:retrieve with force:madpi:deploy to move some sandbox dev org custom objects and supporting customisations to a scratch org, in order to be able to subsequently push a source code package.  I am fetching and deploying a subset of the custom objects via mdapi so that my scratch org has all the necessary custom objects used by Apex controller code (SOQL statements etc) in my source code project.  In my manifest for the mdapi:retrieve and mdapi:deploy I specify all the custom objects and custom fields we seem to need and I've also added,

```
<types>
  <members>Admin.profile</members>
  <name>Profile</name>
</types>
```

Is there something I need to include in my manifest to avoid the error I am seeing when I try and deploy my unpackaged.zip to my scratch org: "Error  unpackaged/objects/Policy__c.object  Policy__c  Profile Search Layout: - System Administrator - not appropriate for object 01I7E0000017CS5"

The sandbox dev org I am fetching metadata from includes a search layout assigned to the system administrator profile - with 3 fields specified for the search layout, 2 of which are custom fields and the other is the standard name field.  The custom object file definition - fetched by force:mdapi:retrieve mentions these bits, that i assume are the relevant parts,

```
    <profileSearchLayouts>
        <fields>NAME</fields>
        <fields>Account__c</fields>
        <fields>Status__c</fields>
        <profileName>System Administrator</profileName>
    </profileSearchLayouts>
```

and

```
<searchLayouts>
        <customTabListAdditionalFields>Type__c</customTabListAdditionalFields>
        <customTabListAdditionalFields>Status__c</customTabListAdditionalFields>
        <customTabListAdditionalFields>Account__c</customTabListAdditionalFields>
        <customTabListAdditionalFields>Line_of_Business__c</customTabListAdditionalFields>
        <customTabListAdditionalFields>Renewal_Date__c</customTabListAdditionalFields>
        <customTabListAdditionalFields>UPDATEDBY_USER</customTabListAdditionalFields>
        <lookupDialogsAdditionalFields>Account__c</lookupDialogsAdditionalFields>
        <lookupDialogsAdditionalFields>Line_of_Business__c</lookupDialogsAdditionalFields>
        <searchResultsAdditionalFields>Account__c</searchResultsAdditionalFields>
        <searchResultsAdditionalFields>Status__c</searchResultsAdditionalFields>
    </searchLayouts>
```

Comment: when you say deploy to scratch are you doing a force:source:push?

Comment: @edralph, I'm doing 2 things: firstly retrieving custom objects from a sandbox org, to deploy to a scratch org where i am developing code.  I am doing this first part with `force:mdapi:retrieve` and `force:madpi:deploy`.  Secondly I want to push an LWC source code project - using `force:source:push` - into this scratch org.  If i do not do the first part,  the Apex controller classes in my LWC fail to compile on push to the scratch org because the controllers depend on those custom objects.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Hard to troubleshoot without being able to poke about - but can you create the custom objects in your scratch org then pull into source?  Then push.